# Python BeautifulSoup returning NoneType during loop

Tags: python, xml, parsing, beautifulsoup

Hey everyone so I made a few edits to my file and am having issues. The Python code grabs page id's from lines of a text document, and sticks the id's into a url template to parse the XML that results. However, the code is returning NoneTypes for every line except the last. Thus, it prints the page ID's (before the for loop) but none of the info within the for loop. Any ideas why?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib

    with open("list.txt") as f:
        for line in f:
            link = "http://somewebsite.com/application?number="+line+"&tab=main&xml=ab14"
            print "Page ID: "+line
            xml_string= urllib.urlopen(link)
            result = soup.find('someXML-tag')
            if result is not None:
                status = result['status']
                print "\nApplication Status: "+status+"\n"
            else:
                print "it was nonetype"
```

The format of each XML document:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <first-XMLtag>
       <someXML-tag id="100001" status="OPEN">
       </someXML-tag>
    </first-XMLtag>
```

my output:

```
PageID: 100000
it was nonetype

PageID: 100001
it was nonetype

PageID: 100002
Application Status: Open
```

There are lines of the text file.

Comment: The syntax for `BeautifulSoup`

Comment: Well yes, I know that, but obviously, there is no `"someXML-tag"` in that soup, that's why it's returning None

Comment: the `someXML-tag` is a tag I'm looking for in my XML document, so `BeautifulSoup` looks through for that specific tag on each page. Also I know for a fact that there is a `someXML-tag` in each one of these pages they all folow the same format.

Comment: Yes I know what BeautifulSoup is, but what is the content of `soup`? I can't help you, and I don't think anyone else can, without seeing that or at least the website you are trying to grab content off

Comment: just edited the question with the format of each XML sorry I did not originally include that

Comment: Hmm, when you defined `soup`, did you do `BeautifulSoup(thecontent, 'xml')`?

Comment: Yes i used `soup = BeautifulSoup(xml_string)`, the bs4 version so I didnt have to use `'xml'`. and `xml_string` is `urllib.urlopen(theurlofthecontent)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, it's not about the soup or anything. It's `line`.

When you are going through a file, each line will have a `\n` at the end (a new line). This is being put on the website URL, thus the soup returns nothing.

Do this:

```
link = "http://somewebsite.com/application?number="+line.rstrip('\n')+"&tab=main&xml=ab14"
```

This strips the new line from the right side of the line

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! You were completely right, I was not at all aware of that newline aspect. Thank you again, it's been confusing me for way too long. +1